# Why is ansible's or conditional giving me unexpected false positives?

Tags: ansible

Given that the following task does not run due to `when` directive resolving to FALSE,

```
 - name: testin1
    command: echo 'hello'
    when: dig_output|d('') == ''
```

and given that the below task also does not run due to `when` directive resolving to FALSE,

```
 - name: testin2
    command: echo 'hello'
    when: "'NOERROR' not in dig_output.results.0.stdout"
```

why is the below task surprisingly running when I expect it to not run either,

```
  - name: testin3
    command: echo 'hello'
    when: (dig_output|d('') == '') or ("'NOERROR' not in dig_output.results.0.stdout")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is the below task surprisingly running when I expect it to not run either,

Because you have confused the YAML quoting in the 2nd step for obligation, but Python treats all non-empty strings as Truthy

Observe:

```
- debug: msg="hello"
  when: False or ("hello world")
```

will run, but

```
- debug: msg="hello"
  when: False or ()
```

will not run. Thus:

```
- command: echo 'hello'
  when: False or ("'NO ERROR' actually the rest does not matter")
```

is what is actually going on with your third example. You likely want:

```
- command: echo 'hello'
  when: (dig_output|d('') == '') or ('NOERROR' not in dig_output.results.0.stdout)
```

because that changes it from a string literal into a `not in` expression, which Python will evaluate for Truthiness